# .NET 6 application is not reading linked appsettings.json

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-6.0

i have a problem with appsettings reading.

I have project1 with `appsettings.json` in it. I want to use the same `appsettings.json` in project2. I added this lines of code in `project2.csproj`:

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="../project1/appsettings.json">
            <Link>appsettings.json</Link>
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
```

And it do his job, `appsettings.json` is copied to `Debug` directory:

[image]

In project i can see it as expected:

[image]

But when i try to run `project2` i am getting error, that `Uri` is not found:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(new Uri(builder.Configuration["KeyVault:Uri"]), new DefaultAzureCredential());
```

When i tried to read `appsettings.json` manually:

```
builder.Configuration
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
    .Build();
```

I get error, that `appsettings.json` is not exist in root folder (where `Program.cs` is placed), not in `Debug` folder. Linking files worked in .NET Core 3.1

How to read linked `appsettings.json` in second project in `.NET6`? It seems like something changed from Core to .NET.

Comment: What does `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` returns to you? Could you check it with debugger? It looks that current working directory for your second project is not the directory with its binaries.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - what is the reason for calling `SetBasePath` and `AddJsonFile`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)` to get path to build directory, not `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`. So try this:

```
builder.Configuration
    .SetBasePath(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location))
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
    .Build();
```

Also, if you have shared configuration file between 2 projects, then it would be better to keep it outside `project1` folder also. Put it to 3rd folder `shared` (or something like that), and reference it by link in both projects.